# Which python buildpack supports pip version 8.1.2?

Tags: python-2.7, ibm-cloud

My python community application failed to deploy because it had pip 8.1.1. Which buildpack has a pip version 8.1.2 that would help me get rid of this error. It helped me solve the problem when I used heroku-buildpack-python that had 8.1.1. Now the problem has reappeared. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Check https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack/releases. It looks like the most recent buildpack is still using pip 8.1.1.

Comment: Thank you ! I've tried this. It didn't work. I've fixed the problem. Pure python webapp in bluemix allows you to upgrade pip by adding pip==8.1.2 line in requirements.txt. I was working with Python-Flask packaged app earlier which didn't allow me to upgrade pip and hence deployment used to fail.